# Axlsx performance reduction after rails 5.2 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, axlsx

I was using axlsx to create a workbook , stream and write to a downloadable xlsx file with rails 4.2. It used to take less than 60 seconds to create a downloadable xlsx file with 40,000 records, along with currency and date formatting. After upgrade to rails 5.2 , no more than 10,000 records can be added under 60 seconds.
Also adding gem 'rails' and gem 'axlsx_rails' in the gem file and doing bundle leads to installation of rails 5.1.5. When I specifically mention rails 5.2, I get

```
axlsx_rails was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
actionpack (>= 3.1) was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on

  actionview (= 5.1.5)
rails (~> 5.2.2) was resolved to 5.2.3.rc1, which depends on
actionview (= 5.2.3.rc1)
```

Does this mean axlsx isn't properly supported with rails 5.2 and hence a performance reduction?

**EDIT**
gem 'rails', '~>5.2.2'
gem 'axlsx_rails'

The above gems now install fine. The performance decrease is still very noticeable. The total time includes call to db, parsing, excel creation and sending for download out of which
`xlsx_package.to_stream.read`
takes much longer than it used to with rails 4.2

Comment: How did you add both gems into your Gemfile? With a version number or without? What command do you run to update the gems? Please share the whole output of the command.

Comment: quick update: 
gem 'rails', '~>5.2.2'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
This works now for some reason. 
But the performance  is still very slow after the update

Comment: I have never used this, but it seems `caxlsx_rails` has taken over `axlsx_rails` https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx_rails

Comment: It has a few new commits over the past few years but the only better and faster option was xlsxtream. But it does not support formatting or styling. Could there be a direct rails dependency for axlsx which is causing its performance decline post upgrade?

Comment: @Eyeslandic It seems to be just a name change, the usage remains same. And the performance of caxlsx and axlsx gems are identical with ruby 5.2 . So The drop in performance must translate to caxlsx as well is what i think. I am not sure tho because I am testing it out on a dummy rails project and not in my actual project.